# When to use pipes and when to redirect?

Tags: linux, redirection

Although this is a basic stuff, but still i wonder.
Consider these two examples.

Case 1:

```
[root@dhcppc0 practice]# cat file1 > wc -l
cat: invalid option -- l
Try `cat --help' for more information.
```

Case 2:

```
[root@dhcppc0 practice]# cat file1 | wc -l
7
```

I wonder, why doesn't redirection work in first case? when to use redirect and when to use pipes? I have been Linux for a long time, but still this basic stuff baffles me.

Please help.

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)! (`wc -l < file1` would have done the same)

Comment: `wc -l file1` is even better.

Comment: @Delan In that particular example, yes (it'll even show you the name of the file) -- otherwise, depends on the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [redirection operator](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/01/inputoutput-redirection-made-simple-in.html) is used to stream a command's `stdout` to a file (`>`), or to stream a file's contents to `stdin` for a command (`<`).

The [pipe operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Piping) (`|`) streams the processes' output (`stdout`) to the next processes' `stdin`.

The only way to make your first case work would be to use a temporary file, so you would need to use two steps:

```
cat file1 > tmpfile
wc -l < tmpfile
```

Comment: Sorry for the stuff lost in the edit! Easier to grasp with an example though :)

Comment: @slhck no worries man, that's why we have revisions :)

Answer (score 3):

You use pipes when you want to connect a FD of one executable to a FD of another. You use redirection when you want to connect a FD of an executable to a file.

Comment: Can you please explain me in terms of commands, what you say is more understandable in case of `pipes( )`.

Comment: `somecommand | someothercommand` `somecommand > somefile` `somecommand < somefile`

Comment: I accept the second answer due to his example, but upvote both.